# Domain goes to localhost

Tags: networking, dns, domain, bind

I have a domain named ejn.nu. On some computers and networks, it sends the user to localhost when it should send the user to my server. When i do "ping", it shows the correct ip for my server and when i do "dig", it shows the correct ip. But when i go to the page in a browser, it just shows me localhost. I belive its something with my DNS server, because it worked before i moved to own bind-servers.
The computers do not have any type of dns-cache.

Do anyone know why?

Comment: It would be useful if you could share your DNS settings for this domain

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is what `dig any ejn.nu` returns:

```
ejn.nu.                 60      IN      SOA     ejn.nu. root.ejn.nu. 18 604800 86400 2419200 604800
ejn.nu.                 60      IN      A       217.211.179.99
ejn.nu.                 60      IN      NS      ns2.sudonet.net.ejn.nu.
ejn.nu.                 60      IN      NS      ns1.sudonet.net.ejn.nu.
ejn.nu.                 60      IN      AAAA    ::1
```

Notice the [`AAAA` record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#IPv6_addresses_in_the_Domain_Name_System). That's the IPv6 address, and `::1` is the loopback address in IPv6.

Basically, any client that prefers IPv6 will request/see the `AAAA` record and visit the loopback interface.

As for fixing this, it depends on how your DNS server is configured and whether you want to support IPv6 on your site. You'll want to either provide the correct IPv6 address, or remove the record altogether.

Comment: Personally, I just now got `ejn.nu. 60 IN AAAA ::ffff:217.211.179.99` -- why not just remove the AAAA RR entirely...?